Drawing an equilateral triangle on lattice square grid
I know that it's not possible to construct an equilateral triangle on lattice square grid if its vertices must be lattice points.
But, suppose you only have a lattice square grid and a straightedge (and a tool like pencil or pen to draw). Is it possible to construct several lines that will then, in fact, create an equilateral triangle?

The height will always be a multiple of $\sqrt{3}$ so I don't think you can do it without a compass.

@Paul, this fact concerned me as well, but I couldn't come up with proof using this so far. But I feel like I have something on my mind that might work as a proof of impossibility...

The only way you can construct a new point is as the intersection of two lines joining two pairs of pre-existing points (either the original lattice points or ones you've already constructed).
Since this is equivalent to solving a pair of simultaneous equations, it's easy to see that you can never construct a point with an irrational coordinate (you start with a subset of $\mathbb{Q}^2$; all coefficients involved will therefore always be rational).
Say there existed an equilateral triangle whose vertices were all in $\mathbb{Q}^2$; then scaling by an appropriate integer factor would result in a triangle in $\mathbb{Z}^2$; but you already know it's impossible to have an equilateral triangle whose vertices are all lattice points.

That's what I was looking for! Thanks. I knew I needed to use the fact of irrationality somehow, and that it should contradict everything I construct using rational numbers like that, but couldn't come up with a way to do it.

By the claim below, no equilateral triangle formed with lattice lines can exist.
Let $L$ be a square lattice in the Euclidean plane.  A line will be called a lattice line if it passes through (at least) two lattice points.
Claim.
There are no two lattice lines spanning an angle of $60$ degrees.
To justify the claim, let us suppose that there are two such lines.  Using translations, we can assume that they intersect in a lattice point, say $O$ (the origin of our frame in the sequel).  Let these lines be $(OA)$ and $(OB)$, with $A = (a_1, a_2)$ and $B=(b_1, b_2)$ two lattice points.  Since
$$
\frac{1}{2}\, OA\,\, OB\, \sin(\widehat{AOB})
= \sigma([OAB])
= \frac{1}{2} |\det(\vec{OA}, \vec{OB})|
= \frac{1}{2}|a_1b_2 -a_2b_1|
$$
and
$$
OA\,\, OB\, \cos(\widehat{AOB})
= \langle \vec{OA}, \vec{OB} \rangle
= a_1b_1 +a_2b_2
$$
we arrive at
$$
\begin{split}
|a_1b_2 -a_2b_1| 
&= OA\,\, OB\, \sin(\widehat{AOB}) \\
&= OA\,\, OB\, \cos(\widehat{AOB})\, \tan(\widehat{AOB}) \\
&= \sqrt{3}(a_1b_1 +a_2b_2).
\end{split}
$$
Taking the square, we get
$$
(a_1b_2 -a_2b_1)^2 = 3(a_1b_1 +a_2b_2)^2.
$$
But this is impossible; inspect the multiplicity of $3$ on both sides of the equality.

It's still not clear to me how you obtained a square on the left side without a square on the right side of equality. Please, could you provide more steps of required mathematical manipulations?

It was an error.  I fixed it!

Do you have problemes with the first equality?  The area of the triangle is given by $OA \cdot OB \cdot \sin(\pi/3)/2$.  The inner product by $OA \cdot OB \cdot \cos(\pi/3)$.

If understand this correctly, the first equality would give $\frac{1}{2} |a_1b_2 - a_2b_1| = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} (a_1b_1 + a_2b_2)$, then by doubling and squaring both sides it would yield $(a_1b_2 - a_2b_1)^2 = 3 (a_1b_1 + a_2b_2)^2$, wouldn't it?

You were right @LLL.  Thanks!  I corrected the my answer.
